# Организация сети raspberrry pi 3 + go pro hero 7

Tags: администрирование, iot

Есть Разбери пи3, к ней по wifi подключена gopro hero7. Задача: получить доступ к udp потоку и http серверу гопрохи, на компьютере подключенном к разбери по ethernet, я хз как настроить iptables для таких целей.

Comment: А при чём тут iptables, если все внутри одной плоской сети? Или нет? Обращаешься по ip и всё.

Comment: сети две: одна, которую раздает гоу про, вторая - локалка

Comment: в локале разбери и компьютер

Comment: Ну сделай для начала одну сеть в локалке. Если там работает - иди уже дальше.